# How to erase elements (or a distance-between A and B) in the a vector

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I would like to check a vector if its elements have both of integers A and B, delete the elements between them and copy to another vector. for instance, there two vector; `vector<> path` and `vector<> v1`

```
   Path         v1

---A***B##    ---AB##
```

so the task is deleting the elements between A and B
here is a C++ code but unfortunately it is not working.Is there any idea about what is the problem ?

```
vector< > Path,v1;

vector<int>::iterator it2,it3;  

int A,B;

it2=find(Path.begin(), Path.end(), A) ; 
it3=find(Path.begin(), Path.end(), B) ; 



vector<int> v1(Path.begin(),Path.end());

if (it2 != Path.end() && it3 != Path.end()) 
{


  if(it2<it3)
  {
     v1.erase(it2+1,it3);
  }
  else
  {
    v1.erase(it3+1,it2);
  }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? You are aware that you create a temporary vector v1 within the if block?

Comment: sorry guys please ignore vector declaration within if block

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you are creating a new `v1` inside your if block, but I'm pretty sure you want to assign to the one that is already there.  You're also passing iterators from the `Path` vector to the erase function of `v1`, causing undefined behavior.  I would also save the work done by `v1.erase` by not adding the unwanted elements in the first place.

```
if (it2 != Path.end() && it3 != Path.end()) 
{
    if(it3<it2)
    {
        std::swap(it2,it3);
    }

    ++it2; // simplifies logic later

    // optional step to possibly save an allocation
    size_t total = std::distance(Path.begin(), it2);
    total += std::distance(it3,Path.end());
    v1.reserve(total);

    v1.assign(Path.begin(), it2);
    v1.insert(v1.end(), it3, Path.end());
}
```

Note that if `A==B`, this adds that element twice.  I'm not sure if this is desired behavior, but it fits with your problem description.

Comment: yeah it definitely fits with my problem, thanks alot.

Comment: but if Path is a vector of vector .. how do you define the iterator of Path.begin(). like Path->begin ??

Comment: also according your code how should I declare vector <> v1 .. I belive I need to know size of vector ??

Comment: @zaratushtra: `std::vector<int> v1;` --- No, you don't need to decide on a size.  `std::vector` dynamically resizes itself upon request.

Comment: @zaratushtra: Your other question, about a vector of vectors, is well beyond the scope of this question.  Make another post about it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no need to traverse the vector two times from its beginning, Instead of using two times algorithm std::find you could use combination of algorithms std::find_first_of and std::find

For example

```
int a[] = { A, B }; // where A and B some integer values

std::vector<int>::iterator first, last;
first = last = path.end();

first = std::find_first_of( path.begin(), path.end(), std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );
if ( first != path.end() )
{
    last = std::find( std::next( first ), path.end(), *first == a[0] ? a[1] : a[0] );
}
```

Now that to move elements in the given range you could write

```
std::vector<int> v1;
if ( first != path.end() && last != path.end() )
{
    ++first;
    v1.assign( first, last );
    path.erase( first, last );
}
```

Or if the original vector shall not be changed then you could write

```
std::vector<int> v1;
if ( first != path.end() && last != path.end() )
{
    ++first;
    v1.assign( path.begin(), first );
    v1.insert( v1.end(), last, path.end() );
}
```